# Cannot return null for non-nullable field - rebing/graphql

Tags: laravel, graphql

I have a problem with GraphQL(rebing-graphql)/Larvel app. App works fine when I query normal GraphQL query(single not nested), but when I query nested one, I face `"debugMessage":"Cannot return null for non-nullable field \"Make Type.name\"`.

Normal query which works fine:

`{model{id,name}}`

Nested query that I want to execute:

`{model{id,name,make_id{id,name}}`

Where am I made mistake?

Thanks in advance.

**Make Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class Make extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'logo',
        'website',
    ];

    public function models()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Model::class);
    }
}
```

**Model Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as MModel;

class Model extends MModel
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'make_id',
        'name',
        'website',
    ];

    public function make()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Make::class);
    }
}
```

**MakeQuery (Graphql part)**

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use App\Models\Make;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;

class MakeQuery extends Query
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Make Type',
        'description' => 'Fetch Make Query'
    ];

    public function args(): array
    {
        return ["id" => ['type' => Type::int()]];
    }

    public function type(): type
    {
        return Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('make'));        
    }

    public function resolve($root, $args)
    {
        if (isset($args['id'])) {
            return Make::where("id",$args['id'])->get();
        }
        return Make::all();

    }
}
```

**MakeType**

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Types;

use App\Models\Make;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Type as GraphQLType;

class MakeType extends GraphQLType
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Make Type',
        'description' => 'Make API Type',
        'model' => Make::class
    ];

    public function fields(): array
    {
        return [
            "id" => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::int()),
                'description' => 'Make ID'
            ],
            "name" => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'Make ID'
            ],
            "logo" => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'Make ID'
            ],
            "website" => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'Make ID'
            ]
        ];
    }


}
```

**ModelQuery**

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use App\Models\Model;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;

class ModelQuery extends Query
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Model Type',
        'description' => 'Fetch Model Query'
    ];

    public function args(): array
    {
        return [
            "id" => ['type' => Type::int()]
        ];
    }

    public function type(): type
    {
        return Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('model'));
    }

    public function resolve($root, $args)
    {
        if (isset($args['id'])) {
            return Model::where("id", $args['id'])->get();
        }
        return Model::all();

    }
}
```

**ModelType**

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Types;

use App\Models\Make;
use App\Models\Model;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Type as GraphQLType;

class ModelType extends GraphQLType
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Model Type',
        'description' => 'Model API Type',
        'model' => Model::class
    ];

    public function fields(): array
    {
        return [
            "id" => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::int()),
                'description' => 'Model ID'
            ],
            "make_id" => [
                'type' => GraphQL::type('make'),
                'description' => 'Model_ID'
            ],
            "name" => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'Model Name'
            ],
            "website" => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'Model website'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like, your source of data is not returning the name field. Try to log/print the results before resolving them with

Comment: I am not PHP developer. But I would recommend renaming `make_id ` with `makeId` and then try.

Comment: @Sodhisaab, Thanks for your comment. I've done the change that you mentioned, and now I get `{"data":{"model":[{"id":20,"name":"ABC","makeId":null}]}}`. No data were fetch for Make

Comment: So your graphql error is gone? Make sure you are mapping fields correctly coming from database to graphql types.

Comment: `return Make::all();` I think here you can check your data!

Comment: @Sodhisaab, Error gone, but still no luck for getting the data (getting null all the time). SQL query (join tables) works fine.

Comment: hmm, then no idea, I do have good knowledge of PHP, Make sure you have data here -> `return Make::where("id",$args['id'])->get()`. if it is possible to host somewhere, then we can debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that you have to done to get your code works:

**First:** Be sure that your tables are full and have valid key relations.

**Second:** In `ModelType` change `make_id` to `makeId`.

**Third:** Reload composer autoload with `composer dump-autoload`.

**Finally:** In your `Model Model` it's better to define a column like below:

```
public function makeId()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Make::class, 'make_id', 'id');
    }
```

I hope these steps would help you.

Comment: That's fix my problem, thanks